# Modified data in a factory that's bound to a controller's scope, it doesn't update

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-factory

I have a pretty simple example

(also available on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/depov5w6/)

I have 2 factories, one which returns an object with the property 'data', (which is bound to the scope of a controller) and another factory that has 2 methods: populateData and pushData. populateData sets the value of dataSource.data to be a new value. pushData pushes a new value onto dataSource.data

```
angular.module("app",[])
  .factory('dataSource', function() { 
    return {
      data: ["Init Data"]
    };
  })
  .factory('dataModifier', function(dataSource) { 
    return {
      populateData: function() {
        dataSource.data = ["data from populateData"];
      },
      pushData: function() {
        dataSource.data.push("new data from push data");
      }
    }
  })
  .controller('dataCtrl', function($scope, dataSource, dataModifier) {
    $scope.data = dataSource.data;
    $scope.populateData = dataModifier.populateData;
    $scope.pushData = dataModifier.pushData;
  })
```

In my view, I have a button that calls pushData and another button that calls populateData. I also display $scope.data

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="dataCtrl" class="container">
    <p>Data: {{data}}</p>
    <button ng-click="pushData()">Push Data</button>
    <button ng-click="populateData()">Set Data To New Value</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you look at the fiddle, if you click the Push Data button, new values get pushed onto the array. However, if you click 'Set Data To New Value', nothing happens and subsequent click to push data do nothing. I think I understand that when you click populate data, you lose the reference to the array that $scope.data was bound to, but why doesn't $scope realize that there is a new value for dataSource.data? How would I fix this? I tried making data a private variable, and using getters and setters, but that did nothing.

I appreciate any insight.

Comment: If you console.log `dataSource.data` inside the click functions, it does look like it's actually changing/populating the array - it's just not rendering it to the DOM which is equally confusing.

Comment: That was the most confusing to me. I'm assuming that when the line `$scope.data = dataSource.data` is evaluate, $scope.data points to a reference of `["Init Data"]`. When `dataModifier.populateData` sets `dataSource.data` to point to a reference of `["data from populateData"]`, $scope.data is still pointing to the reference of `["Init Data"]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of assigning data to the scope, assign whole datasource object to the scope & then use it.

Something like: http://jsfiddle.net/depov5w6/1/

```
.controller('dataCtrl', function($scope, dataSource, dataModifier) {
    $scope.dataSource = dataSource;
    $scope.populateData = dataModifier.populateData;
    $scope.pushData = dataModifier.pushData;
});
```

```html
<div ng-app="app">
   <div ng-controller="dataCtrl" class="container">
   <p>Data: {{dataSource.data}}</p>
   <button ng-click="pushData()">Push Data</button>
   <button ng-click="populateData()">Set Data To New Value</button>
</div>
```

The reason this thing works is because of the way angular's dirty checking works. It compares whole objects to detect if there is any change. When you bind a variable to the scope it creates watch on it. If your assign object to the scope it checks object's value to monitor any changes in properties value. So you need to put watch on the property of the object.

Answer (score 1):

> I think I understand that when you click populate data, you lose the reference to the array that $scope.data was bound to, but why doesn't $scope realize that there is a new value for dataSource.data?

You are correct. When your controller is created (before you  have a chance to click the buttons), it points $scope.data to a list in memory that is also pointed to by dataSource.data. Your `populateData()` function tells dataSource.data to point to a brand new list.. but it doesn't tell $scope.data to stop pointing to the old one.

You could use `$scope.$watch()` to tell when the reference `dataSource.data` changes, and then update `$scope.data`:

```js
.controller('dataCtrl', function($scope, dataSource, dataModifier) {
  $scope.dataSource = dataSource;
  $scope.$watch('dataSource.data', function(data) {
      $scope.data = data;
  });
  $scope.populateData = dataModifier.populateData;
  $scope.pushData = dataModifier.pushData;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change  populateData method like below

```
  populateData: function() {
    dataSource.data. splice(dataSource.data,dataSource.data.length);
    dataSource.data.push("data from populateData");
  }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/depov5w6/3/)