# Updating parent scope from child in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

Im really new to all this, but Im creating a small application to which I could add items with details and update them etc with ionic, cordova and angularjs and Im struggling with following scenario:

I have the ionic views setup as so:

index.html:

```
<div ng-controller="mainController">
  <ion-nav-view>

  </ion-nav-view>
</div>
```

list.html:

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items track by $index | filter:search" ui-sref="detailView({itemId: $index})">{{ item.name }}</ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

add.html:

```
<ion-content>
    <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="text" ng-model="item.name" placeholder="Item title..."/>
    </label>
    <label class="item item-input">
        <textarea cols="30" rows="10" ng-model="item.field1" placeholder="Field1..."></textarea>
    </label>
    <label class="item item-input">
        <textarea cols="30" rows="10" ng-model="item.field2" placeholder="Field2..."></textarea>
    </label>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-33"></div>
    <div class="col col-33">
        <button class="button button-block" ng-click="addItem()">Add</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-33"></div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

Then I have made a factory which I am just  now testing and it looks like this:

factory:

```
.factory('itemFactory', ['$cordovaFile', '$q', function ($cordovaFile, $q) {
var itemFactory = {};

itemFactory.get = function () {
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  $cordovaFile.checkFile('items.json')
    .then(function (result) {

      $cordovaFile.readAsText('items.json')
        .then(function (result) {
          var parsedResult = JSON.parse(result);
          deferred.resolve(parsedResult)
        }, function (err) {
          deferred.resolve([]);
        })

    }, function (err) {

      switch(err.code) {
        case 1:
          $cordovaFile.createFile('items.json');
          deferred.resolve([]);
      }

    });

  return deferred.promise;
};

itemFactory.add = function (itemsFromScope, newItem) {
  var deferred = $q.defer(),
    dataToWrite;
  itemsFromScope.push(newItem);

  dataToWrite = JSON.stringify(itemsFromScope);

  $cordovaFile.writeFile('items.json', dataToWrite, {append: false})
    .then(function (result) {
      deferred.resolve(itemsFromScope);
    },function (err) {
      console.log("Write failed");
      deferred.reject(err);
    });

  return deferred.promise;
};

return itemFactory;

  }]);
```

Then the mainController:

```
  .controller('mainController', function ($scope, itemFactory) {
    $scope.items = [];
    itemFactory.get()
      .then(function (result) {
        $scope.items = result;
      });
  })
```

And then the addController:

```
  .controller('addController', function ($scope, $location, itemFactory) {
    $scope.newItem = {};

    $scope.newItem.name = "";
    $scope.newItem.field1 = "";
    $scope.newItem.field2 = "";


    $scope.addItem = function () {

      itemFactory.add($scope.items, $scope.newItem)
        .then(function (result) {
          $scope.items = result;
        });

      $scope.title="";
      $scope.field1="";
      $scope.field2="";

      $location.path('/').replace();
    };

    $scope.goBack = function () {
      $scope.title="";
      $scope.field1="";
      $scope.field2="";
      $location.path('/').replace()
    };


  })
```

Controllers are loaded to the views with ui-router.

Now this is all good, it might not be the optimal things, but hey, Im just trying things out. But the weird part started when I noticed that in my addController I had `$scope.field1="";` etc instead of `$scope.newItem.field1 = "";`. So I decided to fix them and after that fix, the adding is not working anymore. Instead of adding the right values to my $scope.items in the mainController, I get empty item on it. When I run this on iOS emulator, there is an empty row added to my listing. If I restart the emulator, the new item shows up just fine. I assume something is now refreshed in the wrong time or something, but I cannot figure out what and where. Any hints or explanations?

**EDIT: Added a JS fiddle with same kinda issue to simplify: http://jsfiddle.net/9gx3tfmy/
As you can see the data is added to the array in the factory, but the ui is not updated**

**EDIT2: Actually, nvm, that works on the jsfiddle, but the exact same thing with ionic and it's views is not working. I stripped down the $cordovaFile parts of the code, but same thing, even on the browser. I'll check if I can update the jsfiddle into a similar state**

EDIT3: Now I managed to make it work in jsfiddle, but can't try it at my project untill later today. Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/9yhryL6y/8/

If I dont add the $scope.newItem = {} to the addController, the items is added as undefined.

Comment: hey any way you could put it together in a jsfiddle/jsbin/plunkr or something?

Comment: You can find the jsfiddle URL in the edit part of the question. Hope it clarifies!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your input fields are bound to `$scope.item` in add.html, not `newItem`, so `$scope.newItem` is presumably still the default empty item when you try to add it.

Try:

```
<label class="item item-input">
    <input type="text" ng-model="newItem.name" placeholder="Item title..."/>
</label>
<label class="item item-input">
    <textarea cols="30" rows="10" ng-model="newItem.field1" placeholder="Field1..."></textarea>
</label>
<label class="item item-input">
    <textarea cols="30" rows="10" ng-model="newItem.field2" placeholder="Field2..."></textarea>
</label>
```

Also the reason the JSFiddle isn't working is because you're adding strings like "value1" to the `items` array, but it is expecting an object with a `name` property.

Another thing to be wary of is simply pushing the scope variable into the `items` array because it is not creating a new object, you are just pushing the model the inputs are bound to into the array.  Example: http://jsfiddle.net/9yhryL6y/

The ionic ToDo list demo might be useful for an example of pushing new objects into an array for ng-repeat. https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-todo/blob/master/www/js/app.js

Comment: Added the new jsfiddle into the description. It actually works there now, so have to revisit my code and see what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally figured out this. My problem was two things that I had misunderstood with Angular. I returned a full object from the factory and binded one part of it directly to the scope like so:

```
.controller('myController', ['$scope', 'myFactory', function ($scope, myFactory) {
  $scope.items = myFactory.items;
})])
.factory('myFactory', function () {
  var factoryItems = {};

  factoryItems.items = ['item1', 'item2'];
});
```

now when I updated the array in my Factory, it did not update in the scope. So changed the binding to this:

```
$scope.myFactory = myFactory;
```

And then in the views used the factory like:

```
ng-repeat="item in myFactory.items track by $index"
```

This fixed the issue. This article helped me a lot:

[Modified data in a factory that's bound to a controller's scope, it doesn't update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25275840/modified-data-in-a-factory-thats-bound-to-a-controllers-scope-it-doesnt-upda)